# Getting text from HTML form and pass to JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning HTML/JavaScript and am writing a simple site to test what I've learned so far.
I am trying to get the firstname and lastname entered by the user from an input form and then pass these names to a JavaScript function but for some reason, all I see in my popup window is:

> Hello [object HTMLInputElement]

This is my html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Daynesh's Test Site</title>
    <script>
        function addUser(first, last)
        {
        alert("Hello " + first);
        }
    </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <h1>Registered Users</h1>
    <p>Enter user name:</p>
    <form>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname">
      Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addUser(firstname,'right')">
    </form>
    <hr>
    <h3>Output</h3>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?  I'm sure its something very simple that I'm not understanding here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

in your code

```
onclick="addUser(firstname,'right')"
```

firstname is nothing you don't define it before so you should define it in javascript or
get value from input directly
this your code after fix

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Daynesh's Test Site</title>
<script>
    function addUser(first, last)
    {
    alert("Hello " + first);
    }
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<h1>Registered Users</h1>
<p>Enter user name:</p>
<form>First name: <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastname">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="addUser(document.getElementById('firstname').value,'right')">
</form>
<hr>
<h3>Output</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

i hope my answer help you

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementByName('firstname').value
```

See a more detailed answer at: [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-get-input-text-value)